# Mismatch and Match issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that is not writing anything. I get a Match problem and a mismatch error in the code line below

`rtar = Evaluate("=MATCH(" & ColLetter(rng1.Columns(2).Column) & rng1.Row & "&" & ColLetter(rng1.Columns(3).Column) & rng1.Row & "," & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & "1:" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & last2 & "&" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & "1:" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & last2 & ",0)")`

is highlighted in yellow.

To quickly explain the code and using my Excel image below the expected written result is the grey highlight in cells F8,G8,H8. The data that gets written into these cells only occurs when any set of numbers get written in the cell range, E6:E17 and only then.  The data source is from cells M5 to O17. So as an example when cell E8 (3rd line down) has the 10-1 in it the code would search the data source (3rd line down) and write from the data source cells M8/N8/O8 to cells F8/G8/H8.

Please don’t suggest using a formula because in the arr1 and arr2 I will be using about 50 or more ranges. I only want to use this code and just need help with making the necessary offset and match adjustments.

```
Sub PlaceNumbers()

    Dim c As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
    Dim last1 As Long, last2 As Long, rtar As Long, xtar As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        'create arrays
        arr1 = Array(.Range("D5:H17"))
        arr2 = Array(.Range("L5:O17))                                                             '
        'loop through arrays
        For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            Set rng1 = arr1(i)
            Set rng3 = arr2(i)                                                      
            last1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLetter(rng1.Columns(1).Column)).End(xlUp).Row
            last2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column)).End(xlUp).Row

            For Each c In rng1.Offset(1, 1).Resize(, 1)
                If c <> "" Then
                    rtar = Evaluate("=MATCH(" & ColLetter(rng1.Columns(2).Column) & rng1.Row & "&" & ColLetter(rng1.Columns(3).Column) & rng1.Row & "," & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & "1:" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & last2 & "&" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & "1:" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & last2 & ",0)")
                    xtar = Application.Match(c.Offset(0, -2), Range(ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & rtar & ":" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(1).Column) & last2), 0)
                    With Application.WorksheetFunction
                        c.Offset(0, 1) = .Index(Range(ColLetter(rng3.Columns(2).Column) & rtar & ":" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(2).Column) & last2), xtar)
                        c.Offset(0, 2) = .Index(Range(ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & rtar & ":" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(3).Column) & last2), xtar)
                        c.Offset(0, 3) = .Index(Range(ColLetter(rng3.Columns(4).Column) & rtar & ":" & ColLetter(rng3.Columns(4).Column) & last2), xtar)
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function ColLetter(Collet As Integer) As String

    ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, Collet).Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

[Exec image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j20yF.png)

Comment: For one, I think your formula misses a lot of colons, `:` within your ranges.

Comment: You have a missing closing double quote after `arr2 = Array(.Range("L5:O17`

Comment: change the line `rtar = Evaluate(...)` to `debug.print(...)` and check what's output in the immediate window.  that may find the problem.

Comment: @aucuparia Thanks so much for your reply. I put in  
rtar = debug.print("=MATCH....
The code is still highlighted in red.

Comment: If your image is accurate, why are you not using worksheet change event, and using `offset` `resize` to `copy/paste`?

Comment: @Gmalc hi, because I will be adding 50 plus data ranges when I can get this sample one working. Hey, cam I ask you if I made a mistake on the suggested debug.print above?

Comment: How is `any set of numbers get written in the cell range, E6:E17`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the existing answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959955/8811778) is better (provided it does what you need it to) as it's shorter and easier to maintain/debug.

But I include an alternative, longer version below.

---

If the only logic/rule that results in values in `M8:O8` being written to `F8:H8` is "number of rows down" (i.e. 3 rows down), then I don't think you really need to use `MATCH` function.

If I understand correctly, you just want the `Nth` row of the source data, where `N` corresponds to the row of whatever non-empty cell (in the yellow cells) you're currently processing.

If you change your `For each c in  rng1.Offset(1, 1).Resize(, 1)` to instead loop through the yellow cells one row at a time, you will have access to `N` (otherwise you need to do some row arithmetic: `c.Row - first row of yellow cells + etc...`).

Note that `N` is the variable `rowIndexRelativeToRange` in the code below and is relative to the range, not the worksheet (i.e. first row in the yellow cells, not first row of the worksheet).

```
Option Explicit

Sub PlaceNumbers()

    Dim someSheet As Worksheet
    Set someSheet = ActiveSheet ' Refer to this sheet by name if possible

    With someSheet
        Dim arr1 As Variant
        arr1 = Array(.Range("D5:H17"))

        Dim arr2 As Variant
        arr2 = Array(.Range("L5:O17"))
    End With

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Uncomment when you think code is ready/working

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        Set rng1 = arr1(i)
        Set rng2 = arr2(i)

        ' We have to resize the ranges (to get rid of the first row and first column)
        ' You may want to re-think whether the addresses you specify (when creating arr1 and arr2)
        ' even need to include the first row and first column (e.g. E6:H17 instead of D5:H17)
        ' -- or whether you could just ensure the address passed in already excludes the first row and first column.
        ' It depends on whether you need to use the first row and first column (somewhere else in your code).
        ' But precluding them (if possible) would shorten/simplify the procedure's logic.

        Dim inputColumn As Range
        Set inputColumn = rng1.Offset(1, 1).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1, 1) ' -1 when resizing, otherwise you're looking at range E6:E18, not E6:E17

        Dim dataSourceRange As Range
        Set dataSourceRange = rng2.Offset(1, 1).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1, rng2.Columns.Count - 1)

        Dim rowIndexRelativeToRange As Long ' This index is 1-based and relative to the range, not the worksheet.
        For rowIndexRelativeToRange = 1 To inputColumn.Rows.Count
            If inputColumn(rowIndexRelativeToRange, 1) <> "" Then
                inputColumn(rowIndexRelativeToRange, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = dataSourceRange(rowIndexRelativeToRange, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
            End If
        Next rowIndexRelativeToRange
    Next i

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Uncomment when you think code is ready/working

End Sub
```

Comment: I have been working on this problem for about 2 months. Asking friends and anyone that could give advice or help in any way. Your code not only works its just amazing. I would give you a huge hug if you’re here!!!! Hey Stack Overfow users Chillin is the best!. He’s able to look at the situation and see the solution. Sounds simply but let me tell you a lot of people just can’t do it.

Comment: I uncommented the two Application.ScreenUpdating lines and it still works fine. Did a Google search on this and it says that its used to speed up the code, is that correct? Trying to make sure I understand the connection between arr1 Range and aar2 Range. So for example if I were to put 10 different ranges in arr1 the code would search the corresponding 10 Ranges entered in arr2. So the tenth Range entered in arr1 would get the data from the tenth Range in arr2. I hope I’m being clear. Thank-you so much. Nancy Skyes.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES, I took the `Application.ScreenUpdating` lines from your code, and yes, they're usually to speed things up. Regarding the ranges in `arr1` and `arr2`, yes, your understanding is correct. You may already realise this, but it's important that `arr1` and `arr2` contain an equal amount of ranges (otherwise if `arr1` contains 10 ranges and `arr2` contains only 9 ranges, then you will get an error when you try to access the 10th range in `arr2`). It would also probably be good to have  an `IF` statement or some sort of `Debug.Assert` statement to validate the ranges you're specifying.

Comment: Also, the `For` loop will resize each range in `arr1` and `arr2` to exclude its first row and first column -- so each range's address that you specify should allow for this.

Comment: I will work on that IF statement or some sort of Debug.Assert statement. Thank-you again and have a wonderful weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here because I don't want to put in a comment. Why can't you use a worksheet change event? You can set the target range to multiple ranges. Place this code in the worksheet containing the two areas you showed in your example. When the value in a cell changes it will automatically update the three cells to the right.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6:E17")) Is Nothing Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Range(Target.Address).Offset(, 8).Resize(1, 3).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply and suggestion. I have decided to use the new code created above by Chillin.